# ServletRegistration and MultipartConfigElement cannot being found in spring/maven project

Tags: spring, maven, servlets, pom.xml, multipart

When I try build a spring project, an error occurs in this class:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
          // Create the 'root' Spring application context
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
          rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

          // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext jspContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
          jspContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

          // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
          ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = context.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(jspContext));
          dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
          dispatcher.addMapping("/");
          dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 1024*1024*5, 1024*1024*5*5, 1024*1024));
    }

}
```

the error:

```
[INFO] 5 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.415 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-30T09:31:59-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/285M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project loja: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/loja_on_line/src/main/java/com/webapp/loja/app/WebAppInitializer.java:[3,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MultipartConfigElement
[ERROR] location: package javax.servlet
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/loja_on_line/src/main/java/com/webapp/loja/app/WebAppInitializer.java:[6,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ServletRegistration
[ERROR] location: package javax.servlet
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/loja_on_line/src/main/java/com/webapp/loja/app/WebAppInitializer.java:[27,34] package ServletRegistration does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/loja_on_line/src/main/java/com/webapp/loja/app/WebAppInitializer.java:[27,63] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method addServlet(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet)
[ERROR] location: variable context of type javax.servlet.ServletContext
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/loja_on_line/src/main/java/com/webapp/loja/app/WebAppInitializer.java:[30,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MultipartConfigElement
[ERROR] location: class com.webapp.loja.app.WebAppInitializer
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

my dependencies from pom.xml are:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.2</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-facebook-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Twitter -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Google -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: Ofcourse not those are part of the servlet spec 3.0 you are using 2.5...

Comment: @M.Deinum this is a very old project, and the last time i worked on it, it was building without errors

Comment: @M.Deinum even updating the servlet-api dependency in the pom.xml still don't work.

Comment: Then you are still pulling in the dependency from somewhere.